# Returning array from function - return value does not match (individual case) C++

Tags: arrays, function

I have this function

```
int dctTransform(int matrix[][ndct])
{
int i, j, k, l;

float dct[mdct][ndct];

float ci, cj, dct1, sum;

for (i = 0; i < mdct; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < ndct; j++) {
        if (i == 0)
            ci = 1 / sqrt(mdct);
        else
            ci = sqrt(2) / sqrt(mdct);
        if (j == 0)
            cj = 1 / sqrt(ndct);
        else
            cj = sqrt(2) / sqrt(ndct);
        sum = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < mdct; k++) {
            for (l = 0; l < ndct; l++) {
                dct1 = matrix[k][l] *
                    cos((2 * k + 1) * i * pipi / (2 * mdct)) *
                    cos((2 * l + 1) * j * pipi / (2 * ndct));
                sum = sum + dct1;
            }
        }
        dct[i][j] = ci * cj * sum;
    }
}
return dct;
}
```

And I want in main do something like that

```
matrixZ = dctTransform(matrixZ);
```

I have "return value does not match" error at "return dct" and I can't see what's wrong here, how can I improve it.
MatrixZ[8][8] is int, mdct & ndct = 8.

Comment: You return a matrix, but you declare return type as int (see first line of your code).

Comment: Even if you fix the definition of the function to return a pointer to a float array you can't return the address of a variable local to the function because the stack frame will be destroyed taking the array with it.

Comment: You could pass in the dct that should be filled - that would avoid the lifetime issue.  Or you could declare a struct containing an array and make that the type of your dct because structs can be passed on the stack - just be sure that the array is small enough that it doesn't overflow the stack size.